# Function composition according to relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

- Let $f: A \rightarrow A \ $ and a relation $R_f$ over $A$ $\, $s.t.: $R_f = \left\{(x,y) \in A \times A \mid y=f(x)\right\}$
- Show if the following statements are true or false and explain your choice:

  1. If $\ R_f \ $ is transitive $\implies$ $f \circ f \circ f = f$
  2. If $\ R_f \ $ is symmetric $\implies$ $f \circ f \circ f = f$
  3. If $f \circ f \circ f = f$ $\implies$ $R_f$ is symmetric or $R_f$ is transitive
  4. If $R_f$ is anti-symmetric $\implies$ $f$ is one-to-one or there is $x \in A \ \   s.t. \  f(x)=x$
- So my attempts:

  1. $R_f$ is transitive $\implies$ $x, y, z \in A \ \ s.t. \ \ (x, y), (y, z), (x, z) \in R_f. \ \ $ Then we know $y=f(x) \ \ z=f(y) \ \ z=f(x) \implies z=f(y) = f(f(x)) \implies f = f \circ f$ $\ $ but not three compositions as required.
  2. The same process goes with this.
- About the rest - have no idea.

Comment: If you believe 1 and 2 are false you should construct a concrete counterexample to the claims to demonstrate this

Comment: I don't know if it's false actually. I do think it's true. But I don't understand what's going on here very well to think of a counter-example at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a good start on 1.  In fact, you showed that for any $x$:  $f(f(x))=f(x)$.  But if that is true, then $f(f(f(x)))=f(f(x))=f(x)$, and so indeed $f \circ f \circ f = f$

For 2, if $R_f$ is symmetric, then if $f(x)=y$, then $f(y)=x$. Hence: $f(f(f(x)))=f(f(y))=f(x)$. And so again: $f \circ f \circ f = f$

For 3: OK, so we know $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)$. OK, so let $y=f(x)$ and $z=f(y)=f(f(x))$. So, $f(f(f(x)))=f(z)=f(x)$. Well, how can $f(x)=f(z)$?

Comment: For 3: Actually we know that $\ \ f(f(z)) = f(f(f(x))) \ \  and  \ \ given f \circ f \circ f = f \ \  so \ \  f(f(z)) = f(f(f(x))) = f \circ f \circ f = f = f(x) \ \ $
$\quad$
Yes?